# Accessing SPI flash from /dev

Tags: spi

I've got empty 8Mb flash 25VF064C, what I don't use. So can I use it directly with my Pi?

Yes, I mean directly like /dev/mtd*.

If I can, then how? What do I have to install/recompile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

Nowadays you can just use device tree overlays what Raspberry Pi firmware supports.

In my case, adding `dtoverlay=jedec-spi-nor,flash-spi0-0` to config.txt was enough to pull up `/dev/mtd*0`

---

I needed to edit boardconfig in kernel source.

If anyone else wants to get flash chip working, here's the patch: http://mikroskeem.insomnia247.nl/linux/raspberrypi-patches/mtdflash.patch

Comment: mikroskeem your link is not working could you update it?

Comment: I don't have that patch around anymore, but there is way better solution for that now - use device tree. However as I haven't played around with Raspberry Pi-s for a while now, then I don't have any proper answers.